# How to make the parts of my web page editable in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have requirement to make parts of a dynamic web page that includes **header**, **footer**, **menu**, **content** and **buttons**. I require all of them to be editable/non-editable once i turn on/off editing from admin side.

I already know that **DotNetNuke** already does that for the developer. I like to know what are the merits and demerits if we do it without using DNN. I like to discuss this. Thanks

Comment: This question is kind of broad isn't it? Maybe write some more about what the requirements are, why ASP.net? What kind of website? What kind of server? A question as vague as this requires some more explanation.

Also I can't imagine that there aren't good tutorial websites out there about ASP.net. Have a look at http://nettuts.com I always find them to be a great resource for learning new 'stuff'.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What have you tried so far? I see you're a member of SO for more than 2 years, yet you ask a question like this?

Comment: @Mosselman Thanks. Just rephrased the question.

Comment: @walther I am simply out of touch with ASP.Net. Is it a hardcore requirement to be competent in ASP.Net in order to a member of this site? :S

Comment: I'm not talking about your asp.net skills. I'm talking about the way you're asking the community :) The thing you're asking is a very broad topic and it can be achieved by numerous approaches. I'm really not sure, which part of the solution (of any solution) isn't clear to you and what is exactly the problem you're having. Are you expecting 1000 links? Because that's what you'll get if you won't be more clear about the issue. I don't take "i want something" as an efficient clarification of the problem. Maybe you can answer questions like that, but I can't...

Comment: Maybe have a look at this link: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ Maybe it explains better my thoughts..

Comment: I think your question goes outside of the scope of SO. Maybe try a different site in the network or find a forum to discuss this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this dynamic editing is done with javascript on client side.

I can suggest a nice jQuery code that make editable part of the page with a click. The rest is to handle the save of this edit using some ajax calls. Very nice and simple

Look here a working demo :

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html

and get the code from:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ASP.NET Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhy9ewf1.aspx).
MSDN quote:

*In a Web application scenario, you could offer a complete solution for end users to manage and personalize the application. This could include a set of Web Parts controls that provide the desired features for the site, a consistent set of themes and styles that allow end users to personalize the UI in a consistent way, catalogs of Web Parts controls from which users can select the ones they want to appear on a page, authentication services, and role-based management (for example, allowing administrative users to personalize Web Parts controls and site settings for all users).*